# Plotting the distribution for multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the distribution of multiple columns of my data set. It has over 820.000 rows and 18 columns. I want to plot all columns except the columns with the dummy variables. I have already been able to create a graphic. But I want to have the values of the x-axis on the y-axis because these are the column values and I want to display their distribution for each column.

## 1. Definition of the path

```
setwd("C:/Users/A/Documents/Master BWL/Masterarbeit")
```

## 2. Loading the required packages

```
library(factoextra); library(cluster); library(skmeans); library(mclust); 
library(fpc); library(psda); library(simEd); library (ggpubr);
library(dbscan); library(clustertend); library(MASS); library(devtools);
library(ggbiplot);library(NbClust); library(clValid); library(plotrix)
library(graphics); library(reshape2)
```

## 3. Import csv file

```
WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB_PCA.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";",  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

## 4 Select columns

```
WKA_ohneJB2 <- c(WKA_ohneJB[, "BASKETS_NZ"], WKA_ohneJB[, "PIS"],  WKA_ohneJB[, "PIS_AP"],
             WKA_ohneJB[, "PIS_DV"], WKA_ohneJB[, "PIS_PL"], WKA_ohneJB [, "PIS_SDV"],
            WKA_ohneJB[, "PIS_SHOPS"], WKA_ohneJB[,"PIS_SR"], WKA_ohneJB[, "QUANTITY"]
```

)

```
df <- melt(WKA_ohneJB2)
```

## 5 Plot

```
ggplot(df) + 
geom_col(aes(x= WKA_ohneJB2 , y=value))
```

This is the plot I have generated so far.

[image]

Here is a part of my dataset:

```
dput(rbind(head(WKA_ohneJB, 10), tail(WKA_ohneJB, 10)))
structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 821042L, 821043L, 821044L, 821045L, 
821046L, 821047L, 821048L), BASKETS_NZ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
LOGONS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PIS = c(71L, 39L, 50L, 4L, 
13L, 4L, 30L, 65L, 13L, 31L, 111L, 33L, 3L, 46L, 11L, 8L, 
17L, 68L, 65L, 15L), PIS_AP = c(14L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 1L), 
PIS_DV = c(3L, 19L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 38L, 
8L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_PL = c(0L, 5L, 8L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 6L, 32L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), PIS_SDV = c(18L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 0L), PIS_SHOPS = c(3L, 
24L, 13L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 28L, 2L, 11L, 71L, 16L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_SR = c(19L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 23L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 32L, 1L, 
0L), QUANTITY = c(13L, 2L, 18L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 17L, 8L), WKA = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), NEW_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EXIST_CUST = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WEB_CUST = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), MOBILE_CUST = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), TABLET_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
LOGON_CUST_STEP2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 
821042L, 821043L, 821044L, 821045L, 821046L, 821047L, 821048L
```

), class = "data.frame")

## 6 Plotting histogram

var_to_plot = c("BASKETS_NZ","PIS","PIS_AP","PIS_DV","PIS_PL","PIS_SDV", "PIS_SHOPS","PIS_SR", "QUANTITY")
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for(i in var_to_plot){hist(WKA_ohneJB[,i],xlab=i,main="")}

[image]

I have created several histograms. But the scaling of the axes is wrong. I want the numerical values of the x axis to appear on the y axis and the numerical values of the y axis to appear on the x axis. How does this work? I also want the values to be displayed completely and not as e^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to combine your dataframe all over again. What you need is either a density plot or histogram.

Also as good practice, load only the packages required for plotting, in this case it would be maybe ggplot2 and tidyr.

For example, I just used an example with 5 of the column names I can see in your data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

WKA_ohneJB = data.frame(dummyvar=1:10000,sapply(1:5,rnorm,n=10000))
colnames(WKA_ohneJB)[-1] = c("BASKETS_NZ","PIS","PIS_AP","PIS_DV","PIS_PL")
head(WKA_ohneJB)

  dummyvar  BASKETS_NZ       PIS   PIS_AP   PIS_DV   PIS_PL
1        1  0.92088518 0.9167877 1.956920 4.695379 4.349631
2        2  0.05335686 2.8225161 3.059749 4.317281 5.985579
3        3  1.00141759 3.5743033 2.499662 4.761415 5.886588
4        4 -1.31231486 2.5335004 5.396917 4.364643 5.866026
5        5 -0.65336724 0.2647117 3.203358 4.838659 4.437011
6        6  0.78769080 0.3630670 2.516433 3.826074 3.741611
```

To one of them do:

```
ggplot(WKA_ohneJB,aes(x=PIS)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Or:

```
ggplot(WKA_ohneJB,aes(x=PIS)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

To plot everything at one go, you can try to pivot it long, as you have done with melt, but I don't know if your machine can handle it, so try it for a few variables first:

```
var_to_plot = c("BASKETS_NZ","PIS","PIS_AP","PIS_DV","PIS_PL")
dummyvar = "dummyvar"
ggplot(pivot_longer(WKA_ohneJB[,c(var_to_plot,dummyvar)],-dummyvar),
aes(x=value)) +
geom_histogram() +
facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

If melting the data.frame is too intensive, just use baseR plot:

```
# means 2 rows, 3 columns
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in var_to_plot){hist(WKA_ohneJB[,i],xlab=i,main="")}
```

[image]

Comment: @ StupidWolf This is great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ StupidWolf Could you please explain this code: par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in var_to_plot){hist(WKA_ohneJB[,i],xlab=i,main="")} in detail? Especially the two rows and three columns.To which values do the 2 rows and 3 columns refer?

Comment: if you use plot function in R, it will refresh itself on the device everytime. So if you want to make multiple plots in the same device, screen, you can do par(mfrow=c(2,3)) ; 2 means 2 rows, 3 means 3 columns.. it's like you are expected 6 plots

Comment: if you do like par(mfrow=c(4,4)) you are expecting 16 plots, 4 rows 4 columns https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html

Comment: @ StupidWolf I plotted 9 plots following your code. But the scaling of the axes is wrong. Please see #6 Plotting histogram above.

Comment: Ok what you want to do is very unconventional, you can try this: h = hist(WKA_ohneJB[,i],xlab=i,main="",plot=FALSE) ; barplot(h$counts,names.arg=h$mids,horiz=TRUE,las=2,cex.names=0.7)

Comment: @As123, flipping the histogram is not easy and it's not a very common thing to do. To get the effect you want, regarding labels, you can check https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html